# Changing the order of long lat from geojson file in js

Tags: javascript, geojson

I'm trying to get points out of a geojson file but the coordinate of the points are in the opposite way instead of (x,y) as opposed to (y,x).

On the map I am getting a place that is not really on the map.

How can i get it right in javascript?

This is my code that takes out the points and binds a popup for each point on a map:

```
jQuery.getJSON("data/london_pois.geojson",function(data){
    // add GeoJSON layer to the map once the file is loaded
    L.geoJson(data,{
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
        }
    }).addTo(map);
});
```

Comment: What does `data` look like? Can you show a console.log of it?

Comment: Object
crs:
Object
features:
Array[315580]
Object
geometry:
Object
coordinates:
Array[2]0:-0.0014863,1:51.4779481
length:2

Comment: the array of the coordinates is supposed to be the second place before the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that my issue was not a programming issue, but rather the data set was too large.

After removing a some entries, everything worked fine.